# Python Name Error ('XLMProphetNetTokenizer' is not defined)

Tags: python

I'm working on a cheminformatics project that requires quite a few packages to complete. I'm working in Google Colab.

**TLDR**
Google Colab throws error `NameError: name 'XLMProphetNetTokenizer' is not defined` even though I explicitly load the relevant package with `!pip install transformers`.

**Long Explanation**
To complete my project, I require packages such as `RDKit`, `Moleculekit` from Acellera, and the NLP tool `allennlp`. Google Colab seemed to have issues loading the cheminformatics package `RDKit` so I had to install using conda. I used `!pip install` for the rest of the packages. Code as follows:

```
# Installing RDKit
!wget -c https://repo.continuum.io/miniconda/Miniconda3-py37_4.8.3-Linux-x86_64.sh
!chmod +x Miniconda3-py37_4.8.3-Linux-x86_64.sh
!time bash ./Miniconda3-py37_4.8.3-Linux-x86_64.sh -b -f -p /usr/local
!time conda install -q -y -c conda-forge rdkit

import sys
sys.path.append('/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/')

!apt-get install python-rdkit librdkit1 rdkit-data -qq

# Installing ProphetNet Packages (Needed for ElmoEmbedder)
!pip install transformers

# Installing Moleculekit
!pip install moleculekit

# Installing AllenNLP
!pip install allennlp
```

However, when I call `from allennlp.commands.elmo import ElmoEmbedder`, Google Colab throws the following error: `NameError: name 'XLMProphetNetTokenizer' is not defined`

Looking on the following link, https://huggingface.co/transformers/master/model_doc/xlmprophetnet.html, it seems that I should be able to load the relavent `XLMProphetNetTokenizer` by using `!pip install transformers`. I'm not sure why it still throws the error. Regardless, would appreciate any help.

Comment: I have run this code, and it worked. did you try restarting runtime?

Comment: Why does `ElmoEmbedder` depend on Prophet Net? I work on AllenNLP, and this is news to me.

Comment: @Tuqay, I have tried restarting runtime a few times. Still doesn't work.

Comment: @DirkGroeneveld I'm not sure but Google Colab attributes the error to the line calling ```allennlp.commands.elmo import ElmoEmbedder``` and throws the ProphetNet error.

Comment: Does it give you more information? Does the stack trace go deeper?

Comment: @DirkGroeneveld here is the picture of the error [Imgur Link](https://imgur.com/LKnfvFj)

Comment: I see. AllenNLP depends on `transformers`, and `transformers` is lacking ProphetNet. Looks like your `transformers` installation is broken.